# Smoothness of the metric when going from the interior to the exterior Schwarzschild metric

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

Following (1) and (2), the Schwarzschild metric can be written as:
$$
ds^2 = a(r)\cdot c^2 dt^2 - b(r)\cdot dr^2 - r^2\cdot(d\theta^2 + sin^2(\theta)\cdot d\varphi^2)
$$
where:
$$
a(r)
=
\begin{cases}
\frac14\left(3\sqrt{1-\frac{r_s}{r_g}} - \sqrt{1-\frac{r^2 r_s}{r_g^3}}\right)^2 \qquad \text{if } 0\leq r \leq r_g\\
1-\frac{r_s}{r}\qquad \text{if } r_g\leq r
\end{cases}
$$
$$
b(r)
=
\begin{cases}
\left(1-\frac{r^2 r_s}{r_g^3}\right)^{-1} \qquad \text{if } 0\leq r \leq r_g\\
\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1} \qquad \text{if } r_g\leq r
\end{cases}
$$
Here :

- $r_s=2GM/c^2$ is the Schwarzschild radius of a spherical body of mass $M$
- $r_g$ is the value of $r$ at the surface of the spherical body

The part $r\in [0,r_g]$ is the *interior Schwarzschild solution* while the part $r\geq r_g$ is the *exterior Schwarzschild solution*.

Assume $r_s < r_g$.

Now, I graph $a(r)$ and $b(r)$.
I see that $a(r)$ and $b(r)$ are continuous functions.
I see that $a(r)$ looks fairly smooth.
However, at the transition $r=r_g$, the function $b(r)$ does not look smooth.
Is it normal?
Why would $b(r)$ be not differentiable at the transition from $r<r_g$ to $r>r_g$?

Here is a screenshot for $r_s=1$ and $r_g=2$.

[image]

---

- (1) : [https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Métrique_de_Schwarzschild](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9trique_de_Schwarzschild)
- (2) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_Schwarzschild_metric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of mass has a discontinuity at $r=r_g$ so it entirely reasonable that the metric has a feature that reflects this.

The main point is that while the $a(r)$ function does not have a continuous *derivative* (slope), it *is* continuous, so there is no discontinuity in the metric itself.   That is, the metric does *not* have to be smooth, only continuous.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the non-continuous distribution of mass. However, in classical mechanics the potential energy is differentiable when going from inside $r^2/2 + const.$ to the outside $-1/r$. So I was thinking maybe this should be reflected in the above metric. But yes, if the mass is not continuous, so is $T_{\mu\nu}$, so is $G_{\mu\nu}$, so should some first derivatives of $g_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: The usual matching in cases like follows Israel-Darmois junction conditions (see e.g. arXiv:1604.08930 [gr-qc]) and in the present case (see e.g. arXiv: 1412.7083 [gr-qc]) $a(r)$, $b(r)$, and $a'(r)$ are continuous while $b'(r)$ is discontinuous. The discontinuity in $b(r)$ is proportional to the difference in energy density at $R$ (see eq. (45) of arXiv: 1412.7083 [gr-qc]) which is very large for the interior Schwarschild solution as the density drops from its large constant value to zero at the stellar surface.